Can "fraction" change between a singular and plural noun depending on the context?
Is the following sentence:

...a significant fraction of solute molecules is...

correct, or should it be

...a significant fraction of solute molecules are...

My thinking would be that fraction is a singular noun, and thus the first version is correct, but I've been told that this can change whether it's a fraction of something singular or plural. Is that correct? Can the number of a word change depending from what it refers to?

Are you familiar with how a noun phrase’s numerically transparent premodifiers such as  a lot of and a number of work for purposes of grammatical agreement between that noun phrase and the finite verb it governs?

I'm not! @tchrist, could you please elaborate more?

Sometimes a fraction is a piece of and sometimes pieces of.

There are lots of similar questions e.g. handful, selection, groups...

See ... percentage – a singular-form verb is required ... for the very closely related 'a large percentage of the N is/are'.

I think it depends on whether it's a fraction of a countable set of objects or a non-countable mass noun. So

A significant fraction of solute molecules are ...

vs.

A significant fraction of the solute is ...

When it's countable, you can replace "a significant fraction" with an actual number, e.g. "10 of the solute molecules", and the grammar is the same.

There's more to this. Those who use notional agreement will probably  (see Ludwig.guru) use 'A large fraction of the population are struggling to make ends meet' whereas those favouring formal agreement will opt (see Ludwig.guru) for 'A large fraction of the population is struggling to make ends meet'. Regarding the population as homogeneous or discrete.
